# Is it possible to avoid ANR caused by com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView?

Tags: android-anr-dialog, admob

Occasionally the following code causes Application Not Responding (ANR):

```
//Google Ads
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//adView.loadAd must be called on a UI thread
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The method causes ANR is loadAd(). The probability for it to cause ANR is very low (well below 1%), but I still want to eliminate it completely.  Is there a way to do it?